# pyodbc connection using existing ODBC configured credentials

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, odbc, credentials

I have configured an ODBC in windows in which I specified the user and password for a Microsoft SQL Server database and got a successfull connection when testing it during configuration, and need to connect to it with Python (pyodbc) not having to specify the user and password again in the connection string in my Python script due to security issues, but want pyodbc to use the already ODBC configured user and password. How should I specify it in the connection string?

I am currently using the following connection string for sqlalchemy:

```
import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
en = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://@myodbc')
sq = 'Select [Name], [Address] From [dbcustomer].[dbo].[customers]'
cust_info = pd.read_sql_query(sq,en)
```

But it tries to connect using my local Windows session credentials, instead of using the ODBC configured ones in 'myodbc'.

Any help would be appreciated

Jorge

Comment: Have you verified that the DSN you created really does include the credentials (UID and PWD)? You can use [dump_dsn](https://github.com/gordthompson/dump_dsn) to check that.

Comment: You are right, @GordThompson Password is not saved. Is there a way to save it during ODBC configuration?

Comment: That depends on the ODBC driver's setup program. The setup program for Microsoft's ODBC Drivers for SQL Server does not save the credentials in the DSN because the driver will ignore any `UID=` and `PWD=` values that might be in the DSN — even if we enter them manually — so there's no point. In other words, with Microsoft's driver we need to specify either `Trusted_Connection=yes`, or `Trusted_Connection=no` with both `UID=` and `PWD=` in the connection string.

Comment: as long as you're sql server has been configured to let you use windows authentication this should work: conn_string = 'mssql+pyodbc://@<server>/<database>?trusted_connection=yes&driver=ODBC+Driver+13+for+SQL+Server'. there's no way to use separate creds that i know of without including them in the conn string. check with your DBA to have permissions changed to match the creds you're inputting.

Comment: alternatively you can hold credentials in a config file to allow you to share code but you'll still have the uid & pw saved...just locally as json or something and not in a python program